# Regular expression to match with optional following text

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I'm very new to regular expressions and I need some help finding the correct regular expression.

I have a text file of the form:

```
apple 4
bananas 5
bananas 5 7
apple 3
apple 6
bananas 3
bananas 4 5
apple 3
bananas 9
```

I am looking for a regular expression that will match the last occurrence of `"bananas.*"` after each `"apple.*"`, keeping in mind that for every `"apple.*"` there may be no `"bananas.*"`. The regex should match to the following:

```
bananas 5 7 
bananas 4 5
bananas 9
```

Thanks in advance. I am doing this in python if that helps.

Comment: What would help is showing what you've tried and telling us what issue you ran into

Comment: Also, what does recursive have anything to do with this?

Comment: The recursive nature comes into this being similar to a push-pop stack.

Comment: Does it have to be a regular expression? I think a loop and some `.startswith()` calls would be much more readable...

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a need for a regex here.  Just iterate through the lines and use `if 'apple' in line:`, for example, that keeps track of flags for when it found an apple to look for a banana next.

Answer (score 1):

It actually **is possible** with regular expressions:

```
^apple.+[\n\r]
(?:(bananas.*)[\n\r]?)+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/meA9vY/1), mind the different modifiers and use group `1` of every match.

---

As full `Python` code:

```
import re

string = """
apple 4
bananas 5
bananas 5 7
apple 3
apple 6
bananas 3
bananas 4 5
apple 3
bananas 9 
"""

rx = re.compile(r"""
        ^apple.+[\n\r]
        (?:(bananas.*)[\n\r]?)+
        """, re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)

bananas = [m.group(1) for m in rx.finditer(string)]
print(bananas)
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/xqlxSO).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that needs to be recursive.  Here's a pattern that will work:

```
>>> fruit_lit = """apple 4
bananas 5
bananas 5 7
apple 3
apple 6
bananas 3
bananas 4 5
apple 3
bananas 9"""

>>>  re.findall(r'apple\s*\d*\s*\n(?:bananas\s*(?:\d+\s*)+\n)*(bananas(?:\s*\d+)+)\s*', fruit_list)
['bananas 5 7', 'bananas 4 5', 'bananas 9']
```

And as many of the comments mention, regex might not be the best way to get what you're trying to find.  Iterating over each line and testing `line.starswith('apple')` then `line.startswith('banana')` for each subsequent line might be a better way.